# ï»¿ is getting added in the last line of file while fetching data from mysql "INTO OUTFILE" query

Tags: mysql, select-into-outfile

I have written a mysql query which selects some rows from a table depending on a condition and writes it to a txt file. But i realized, its inserting a set of additional characters `ï»¿`in the last line of the file. Here is the query

```
$sQuery  = " ( ";
            $sQuery .= " SELECT number ";
            $sQuery .= " INTO OUTFILE '".$outputfile_ndnd."' ";
            $sQuery .= " FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  ";   
            $sQuery .= " LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' ";
            $sQuery .= " FROM `".$database."`.$temp_table_name";
            $sQuery .= " WHERE number NOT IN (SELECT number FROM `dnd`.`dnd` )";
            $sQuery .= ")";
```

Any suggestion to stop that from inserting in to file? (I saw the other similar questions asked, they say its `UTF-8's BOM`, but didnt get how to stop it in my case of mysql query)

Comment: Last line? They should be the first three bytes.

Comment: Yes, in last line, it should be a number, but its ending like is ï»¿9876543210, but i want only 9876543210.

Comment: I can't test this, but try adding `CHARACTER SET binary` after the outfile parameter, before `FIELDS TERMINATED BY`. It might disable the conversion.